# Java Long toString returns exponential notation format

Tags: java, format, tostring

on some servers my service written on java:

```
 Long bufValue = ((LocalDateTime) fieldValue).toDateTime().getMillis();
                value = bufValue.toString();// value = 1.377216E12
```

returns string in exponential notation format e.g. 1.377216E12
What is the best way to overcome this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `String.format`-

```
String.format("%d", value);
```

Or-

```
value = Double.valueOf(bufValue.toString()).longValue();
```

Comment: @SteveKuo No. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#longValue()

Answer (score 1):

```
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("0");
value = formatter.format(bufValue);
```